# bootstrap visable-xs not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

trying to create separate sections on a site, one that shows for mobile <768 px,  and another that shows for all other resolutions. In a mobile display, it appears to display properly. In any bigger resolutions, it displays both sections.

The hidden-xs class works to hide the section (row) for mobile, but the visable-xs class does not work to only show the section (row) in mobile. Hopefully its something obvious I am overlooking.

```
 <!-- Desktop/Tablet Monthly Memberships -->
        <div class="row hidden-xs">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="top-pad">Monthly Memberships<br><br></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
                <div class="rates-text clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="photos/flower_icon.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <h3 class="mr-top-space"><u>Purple</u></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="photos/flower_icon.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div>
                        &nbsp; 
                        <p>$60</p>
                        <p>Unlimited Floor Classes</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p><a href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/asp/main_shop.asp?pMode=0&tabID=3" class="page-scroll btn btn-primary pull-right btn-class-signup">Sign-up&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></p>
                </div>         
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                <div class="rates-text clearfix">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <img src="photos/flower_silver.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">       
                        <h3 class="mr-top-space"><u>Silver</u></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <img src="photos/flower_silver.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div> 
                    &nbsp;
                    <p>$90</p>
                    <p>Unlimited Floor Classes</p>
                    <p>3 Aerial Yoga Classes</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p><a href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/asp/main_shop.asp?pMode=0&tabID=3" class="page-scroll btn btn-primary pull-right btn-class-signup">Sign-up&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></p> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                <div class="rates-text clearfix"> 
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="photos/flower_gold.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                </div> 
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <h3 class="mr-top-space"><u>Gold</u></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="photos/flower_gold.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                </div> 
                &nbsp;
                <p>$120</p>
                <p>Unlimited Floor Classes</p>
                <p>6 Aerial Yoga Classes</p>
                <p>10% off all Workshops</p>
                <p><a href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/asp/main_shop.asp?pMode=0&tabID=3" class="page-scroll btn btn-primary pull-right btn-class-signup">Sign-up&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Mobile Monthly Memberships -->
        <div class="row visable-xs">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="top-pad">Monthly Memberships<br><br></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <div class="rates-text clearfix">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src="photos/flower_icon_mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h3 class="mr-top-space"><u>Purple</u></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src="photos/flower_icon_mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>$60</p> 
                        <p>Unlimited Floor Classes</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p><a href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/asp/main_shop.asp?pMode=0&tabID=3" class="page-scroll btn btn-primary pull-right btn-class-signup">Sign-up&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></p>
                </div>         
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center top-space">
                <div class="rates-text clearfix">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src="photos/flower_silver_mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-xs-4">       
                        <h3 class="mr-top-space"><u>Silver</u></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="photos/flower_silver_mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                    </div> 
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>$90</p>
                    <p>Unlimited Floor Classes</p>
                    <p>3 Aerial Yoga Classes</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p><a href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/asp/main_shop.asp?pMode=0&tabID=3" class="page-scroll btn btn-primary pull-right btn-class-signup">Sign-up&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></p> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center top-space">
                <div class="rates-text clearfix"> 
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="photos/flower_gold_mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                </div> 
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h3 class="mr-top-space"><u>Gold</u></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="photos/flower_gold_mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block flower-icon">
                </div> 
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>$120</p>
                <p>Unlimited Floor Classes</p>
                <p>6 Aerial Yoga Classes</p>
                <p>10% off all Workshops</p>
                <p><a href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/asp/main_shop.asp?pMode=0&tabID=3" class="page-scroll btn btn-primary pull-right btn-class-signup">Sign-up&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

added classes:

```
.top-pad {
padding-top: 30px;
}

.rates-text {
background-image: url(../photos/asanoha.png);
background-color: rgba(239,239,239, 0.4);
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid black; 
}

.flower-icon {
margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn-class-signup {
margin: 20px;
}

.top-space {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Problem can be seen here, the repeating monthly memberships.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `visible-xs` instead of `visable-xs`

Comment: gosh, thank you. I knew it was something that was gonna make me look like an idiot.